# Limit number of points retrieved in a postgis query?

Tags: python, leaflet, postgis, geopandas

**Short question:** Suppose having a table in postgis that have a geometry, a circle of 1000 points, is it posible to retrieve some points that allows to get the overall form of the geometry?
For instance:
Select geometry from table with a "resolution" of 100 points

**Long question:** I have geometries stored in a table that need to draw in a  web page using leaflet. Currently all is working and the architecture is as follows:

[image]

But I need to improve the performance of the web page because the time of loading is hight due to big geojson that needs to be retrieved and build from the geometry stored in the DB is consuming a lot of bandwith. Some idea that I have is instead of retrieving all points that make the circle (geometry), retrive only a subset that likewise allows drawing the geometry. And in case the user does some zooming on an specific area of the geometry the app will retrieve only the part that is visible in the leaflet map and refresh the geometry asincronically to increase the resolution (number of points of the geometry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGIS has a function called `ST_Simplify` ([see docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Simplify.html)) that does exactly that. It uses the Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm ([see Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)) to simplify (multi)linestrings and (multi)geometries. You'll probably need some cache for the different resolutions at the different zooms.

Comment: select ST_Npoints(geometry), 
          ST_NPoints(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology( geometry,0.001)), 
ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology( geometry, 0.001 )  from province p;

Instead of getting 5667 point I get 592. It was exactly what I was looking for.